# I conducted some experiment and I want to know the resulting redish black thing

Tags: acid-base

I placed two electrodes in a jar
and poured the sparking water with lemon flavor.
After about 5 hours, the water turned to blue and
the negative probe had the redish black thing.
I'd like to know what it is. Please, reply for me.

1. Materials : 9V battery, battery holder&wire, jar, copper wire and trevi (sparkling 
   water)
   [image]
2. Connecting battery
   [image]
3. After about 5 hours
   [image]
4. Result : redish and black thing.
   [image][image]

Comment: 1. Can you please list the content (ion composition) of the sparkling water? 2. In your text you wrote that you're added lemon flavour. What exactly does this mean? Fresh lemon juice? Something you've bought? If so, does it have a composition list? BTW, this lemon flavour is missing in your list of materials.

Comment: I guess the composition of the sparkling water is irrelevant. It is obviously copper that is responsible for both phenomena (blue solution and reddish-black dirt).

Comment: 1-2. The sparking water is just one I bought. "Composition List : 정제수(distilled water), 이산화탄소(CO2), 천연향료(레몬향, natural flavor; lemon) 0.02%". I'm sorry for lack of english skill.

Comment: @IvanNeretin well, knowing the water composition allows us to rule out

Answer (score 1):

Solvated copper(II) ions for the blue color, copper(II) oxide for the black (as hinted by IvanNeretin). To prove this hypothesis, one could dissolve the copper oxide in sulphuric acid, neutralize the solution and add ammonia. The deep blue color indicates the $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^{2+}}$ complex. The latter can also be done for the blue solution currently present.

Comment: ...and metallic copper for the red.

Comment: Thank you for answering to me. You mean that (1) the positive probe : Cu -> Cu(ll) + 2e    (2) the negative probe : Cu(ll) + 2e + H2O -> CuO + H2, am I right?